# How to undo git init --bare in existing remote repository

Tags: git

I ran "git init --bare" in an existing remote repository by mistake. Git says it reinitialized the existing git repository. Is there any way to undo this action?

Comment: Clone it again from a remote?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I performed this in the remote.

Comment: Force push from a local copy?

Comment: According to the documentation, `git init` in an existing directory shouldn't overwrite anything.

Comment: Was it a bare repository or a regular repository before you ran `git init --bare`?

Comment: If I run `git init --bare` in an existing repo, I get the "Initialized empty Git repository ... " message, but the existing history is unaffected. There shouldn't be anything to undo.

Answer (score 2):

actually 'git init --bare' only adds extra files into your repo. You can just remove them.

```
% cd your-repo
% git status

untracked files:
(use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

    HEAD
    config
    description
    hooks/
    info/

% git clean -f -d

 Removing HEAD
 Removing branches/
 Removing config
 Removing description
 Removing hooks/
 Removing info/
 Removing objects/
 Removing refs/
```

Your directory is now clean as before the 'git init'

Comment: I thought the "git init bare" command created all these files. I cannot do a git status on the remote repository. It says "fatal: this operation must be run in a work tree".

Comment: `git init --bare` can only be done on some local repository. it does not remove any files in that repo. If you have not removed the `.git` directory manually, the above should work with no issues. make sure that you `cd` into  the local repo which you initialized.

Answer (score 1):

I would go the hard way... move the whole directory to a backup dir, create a new empty dir with the previous name of the repo directory and copy (recursively) the .git dir from the old repo to the new one. So, let's suppose that your repo is in /home/blah/one_repo (on the remote server)

```
cd /home/blah
mv one_repo one_repo_back
mkdir one_repo
cp -R one_repo_back/.git one_repo/
```

If you look from another host, the repo should look the way it has always looked before.... now, if you want to also get the back the files that were in the working tree:

```
cd one_repo
git checkout -f the-branch
git reset --hard
```

And you should be done.